# linker error with derived class and virtual function

Tags: c++, linker

the following code produces a linker error

```
//baseClass.h
class baseClass
{
   virtual void update(InputManager& input);
}

//baseClass.cpp
//defines update

//derivedClass.h
class derivedClass : public baseClass
{
   void update(InputManager& input);
}

//derivedClass.cpp
//defines update
```

the error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"derivedClass::derivedClass(float, float)", referenced from:
  _main in main.o
```

but the following code compiles fine:

```
//baseClass.h
class baseClass
{
   virtual void update(InputManager& input);
}

//baseClass.cpp
//defines update

//derivedClass.h
class derivedClass : public baseClass
{
   void update(InputManager& input){}
}
```

Why is this? Why can't I define derivedClass's update function outside of the class definition?

Comment: working fine for me...

Comment: The implementation looks like this: `void derivedClass::update(InputManager& input) { //code }` I've tried adding derivedClass.cpp to compile sources on xcode, but this duplicates the file for some reason.

Comment: That error is saying the constructor for `derivedClass` that takes two `float` as parameters cannot be found at link time (coincidence, as outside of that error message, it cannot be found *at all* in this question's code). it has nothing to do with `update`. Stop posting "like this" code and start posting *real* code that produces your actual error.

Answer (score 0):

what I understood from your explanation is you are not providing body of function `void update(InputManager& input);`
in the derived class. you must provide body, since you overridden it, do some thing in overridden function body.
As you provided second code snipped it is compiling fine as you provided function body (empty at-least, it must not be empty, but for compiler, its OK).